# Putting order by inside with(), in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a controller that filters the columns in it's table based on the variable received in the get query, then it returns it with another table's value based on the id of the variable gotten, But now for the `$filter_by_name` condition I want to filter by the `first_name` column in the users table, please how can i do that, i.e I want to return the users table ordered by their first_name column

DB-STRUCTURE

COMPANY-USERS TABLE

```
id  company_id  user_id role created modified active department_level
```

USERS TABLE

```
id 
first_name 
last_name 
email 
password 
active_company 
profile_photo_id 
verified 
active 
remember_token 
created 
modified
```

Company-users Controller

```
public function getCompanyUsers($companyId)
{
    $filter = strtolower(Input::get('filter'));
    if($filter && $filter === 'on' ){
        $filter_by_date = strtolower(Input::get('filter_by_date'));
        $filter_by_name = strtolower(Input::get('filter_by_name'));
        $filter_by_role = strtolower(Input::get('filter_by_role'));
        if($filter_by_date){
            if($filter_by_date == 'oldest'){
                $users = CompanyUser::where('company_id', $companyId)->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
                ->with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
                return $users;
            }else{
                $users = CompanyUser::where('company_id', $companyId)->orderBy('created', 'ASC')
                    ->with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
                return $users;
            }
        }elseif ($filter_by_name){
            if($filter_by_name == 'ascending'){
                $users = CompanyUser::where('company_id', $companyId)->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')
                    ->with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
                return $users;
            }else{
                $users = CompanyUser::where('company_id', $companyId)->orderBy('first_name', 'DESC')
                    ->with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
                return $users;
            }
        }elseif($filter_by_role){
            if($filter_by_role == 'member'){

                $users = CompanyUser::where(['company_id' => $companyId,'role'=>'Member'])->with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
              //  dd($users);
                return $users;
            }elseif($filter_by_role == 'manager'){
                $users = CompanyUser::where(['company_id' => $companyId,'role'=>'Manager'])->with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
                return $users;
            }else
                $users = CompanyUser::where(['company_id' => $companyId,'role'=>'Admin'])->with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
            return $users;
        }
    }
    $users = CompanyUser::where('company_id', $companyId)->
    with(['user','user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])->get();
    //dd($users);
    return $users;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure  I understood you, you want to return the users from your query ordered by their first_name column?

Comment: Yes I want to return the users ordered by their first_name column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass closer functions when eager loading to add constrains like that, see more on [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$users = CompanyUser::with(['user'=> function ($query) {
                                   $query->orderBy('first_name', 'desc');
                                 }
                           ])
                      ->where('company_id', $companyId)
                      ->get();
```

Comment: It says method `orderby` not found in subject class, It isn't ordering it

Comment: also, what is user.userDepartments?

Comment: Thanks I have seen it

Answer (score 2):

You have to do orderBy on a relational model like below:

```
 $users = CompanyUser::where('company_id', $companyId)
->with(['user' => function($subQuery){
     $subQuery->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC');
}])
->with(['user.userDepartments','user.userDepartments.department'])
->get();

return $users;
```

Comment: It says method orderby not found in subject class, It isn't ordering it

Comment: are you getting this error in any editor or in browser?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add column 'first_name' in the 'COMPANY-USERS' TABLE

And now you can do order by ('first_name','ASC').
I think its not the best way but no other idea comes in my head.